# python time.strftime %z is always zero instead of timezone offset

Tags: python, timezone, strftime

```
>>> import time
>>> t=1440935442
>>> time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S %z",time.gmtime(t))
'2015/08/30-11:50:42 +0000'
>>> time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S %z",time.localtime(t))
'2015/08/30-13:50:42 +0000'
```

The offset stays the same +0000, but I expect '2015/08/30-13:50:42 +0200'

The timezone is correct, as the command is interpreting capital %Z as it should

```
>>> time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S %Z",time.localtime(t))
'2015/08/30-13:50:42 CEST'
```

Unix date works like I want

```
$ date -u --date @1440935442 +"%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S %z"
2015/08/30-11:50:42 +0000
$ date --date @1440935442 +"%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S %z"
2015/08/30-13:50:42 +0200
```

Comment: I see the same result, but note in the documentation: "The use of %Z is now deprecated, but the %z escape that expands to the preferred hour/minute offset is not supported by all ANSI C libraries."

Comment: (I can't see anything else that should do the same thing with strftime though. Perhaps you should look at the datetime module?)

Comment: as I'm on a standard linux system, I expect %z to be in the ansi lib. But it's not working as expected. This is a bit sad. I will look into datetime, but this means probably all my code needs changing.

Comment: @JonSkeet: the issue is that `time.localtime(t)` result has no timezone info attached on Python <3.3 (apart from `tm_isdst`). OPs code works fine in Python 3.3+ on Linux where the returned `struct_time` has `tm_zone`, `tm_gmtoff` attributes.

Answer (score 4):

[As documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html):

> Most of the functions defined in this module call platform C library
>   functions with the same name. It may sometimes be helpful to consult
>   the platform documentation, because the semantics of these functions
>   varies among platforms.

[and](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime):

> Additional directives may be supported on certain platforms, but only
>   the ones listed here have a meaning standardized by ANSI C. To see the
>   full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the
>   strftime(3) documentation.

...

> The use of %Z is now deprecated, but the %z escape that expands to the
>   preferred hour/minute offset is not supported by all ANSI C libraries.

`time.strftime()` uses C `strftime()` and therefore the behavior is platform-dependent. `%z` should work on POSIX but [`%z` may return the same result as `%Z` on Windows](http://bugs.python.org/issue20281). `%z` is not documented on Python 2 and therefore `time` module should return whatever C `strftime()` returns on the given platform without any changes.

The same code works in Python 3 on my machine:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = 1440935442
>>> time.strftime("%Z%z", time.gmtime(t))
'GMT+0000'
>>> time.strftime("%Z%z", time.localtime(t)) 
'CEST+0200'
```

Your issue seems to be Python 2 specific:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = 1440935442
>>> time.strftime("%Z%z", time.gmtime(t))
'CET+0000'
>>> time.strftime("%Z%z", time.localtime(t))
'CEST+0000'
```

Note: `time.strftime('%Z%z')` returns `'CEST+0200'` on both Python 2 and 3. The difference might be explained by the absence of `tm_zone`, `tm_gmtoff` attributes in Python <3.3. Neither `time.gmtime()` nor `time.localtime()` provide timezone info on Python 2 (apart from `tm_isdst` that is why `time.gmtime()` leads to `CET`). `time.strftime('%Z%z')` uses C `localtime()` and therefore it may provide `tm_zone`, `tm_gmtoff` even on Python 2.

If you need portable behavior and to support timezones that might have different tzname, utc offset in the past; you could use `pytz` tzinfo objects (e.g., via `tzlocal` module) that provide access to the historical timezone database:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1440935442, tzlocal.get_localzone()).strftime('%Z%z')
'CEST+0200'
```